# MySQL - Inserting extra blank row on executing query

Tags: php, mysql, row

Here is my code of program:

```
<?php



error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

$host           = "localhost";
$user_name      = "usr";
$pwd            = "pwd";
$database_name  = "my2"; //assuming you created this

mysql_connect($host, $user_name, $pwd)or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db($database_name)or die(mysql_error());

$datee              = $_POST['datee'];
$time               = $_POST['time'];
$destination        = $_POST['destination'];
$days               = $_POST['days'];
$cab                = $_POST['cab'];
$route              = $_POST['route'];
$full_name          = $_POST['full_name'];
$address            = $_POST['address'];
$mobile_number      = $_POST['mobile_number'];
$pickup_location    = $_POST['pickup_location'];

$query2 = "SELECT `order_number` FROM `count` WHERE 1";
$countQuery = mysql_query($query2)or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($countQuery))
{
    $order_number = $row["order_number"];
}

$query3 = "UPDATE `count` SET `order_number` = '".$order_number."'+ 1 WHERE 1";
mysql_query($query3)or die(mysql_error());

$query1="INSERT INTO booking VALUES     ('".$datee."','".$time."','".$destination."','".$days."','".$cab."','".$full_name."','".$ad       dress."','".$mobile_number."','".$pickup_location."','".$route."','".$order_number."')";
mysql_query($query1)or die(mysql_error());
?>

<html>
<body>
<div style="border:1px solid black;background-color:#FAFA23;width:600px;height:100px;">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<?php
echo "Your order number is :".$order_number;
?>
</td>
</tr>

<tr align="center">
<td>Thank you for booking, We will contact you soon ! </td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

On executing this program one extra row is being added every time.
Please tell me what is the problem in this code?
Also when I want to increase the value of column by 1 then it is increasing by 2..see- `order_number=order_number+1;`

Comment: order_number + 1 what is it.?? order_number is not a variable use $order_number + 1 in update query..

Comment: order_number is a column name in table "count"

Comment: i know it table field but in update query you use SET `order_number`=order_number+1 that must be as SET `order_number`=$order_number+1...you need to define $order_number variable.

Comment: ok and what about the extra blank row.

Comment: order_number=$order_number+1 adds value 1 and it does not increase value in the field.

Comment: because you did not have $order_number variable value so it just add 1...what actually you want...update question

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', true);

    $host           = "localhost";
    $user_name      = "usr";
    $pwd            = "pwd";
    $database_name  = "db"; //assuming you created this

    mysql_connect($host, $user_name, $pwd)or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db($database_name)or die(mysql_error());

    $datee              = $_POST['datee'];
    $time               = $_POST['time'];
    $destination        = $_POST['destination'];
    $days               = $_POST['days'];
    $cab                = $_POST['cab'];
    $route              = $_POST['route'];
    $full_name          = $_POST['full_name'];
    $address            = $_POST['address'];
    $mobile_number      = $_POST['mobile_number'];
    $pickup_location    = $_POST['pickup_location'];

    $query2 = "SELECT order_number FROM `count` WHERE 1";
    $countQuery = mysql_query($query2)or die(mysql_error());

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($countQuery))
    {
        $variable = $row["order_number"];
    }

    $query3 = "UPDATE `count` SET `order_number` = ''".$order_number."'+ 1 WHERE 1";
    mysql_query($query3)or die(mysql_error());

    $query1="INSERT INTO booking VALUES ('".$datee."','".$time."','".$destination."','".$days."','".$cab."','".$full_name."','".$address."','".$mobile_number."','".$pickup_location."','".$route."','".$variable."')";
    mysql_query($query1)or die(mysql_error());
?>
```

I have updated your question's code here try it and they see it's work.

Do not forget to create `$order_number` variable.

Comment: its not working ..and i think this is due to that this code adds an extra row in table 'booking' having value of column 'order_number' only and which is one more than previous row.

Comment: same problem as before it increases the order_number by two and adds an extra row

Comment: @user2085757 in which table it add extra row..?? and order_number is added two because you may have already incremented it with one and again in update query you are incrementing it with one more...pls update question with all code...pls

Comment: I have edited my question with whole code..now please edit it such that it works well..